# Direct traffic from host to one virtual machine then to another in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have two services (firewall and DPI) running on two different virtual machines, and there is a server connected to the network which there are files on it to download. So I want VM2 to be able contact the server to download some files, but the traffic should first goes to VM1 (which is firewall), then goes to VM2. Is this possible with VirtualBox? If yes, How? Here is the photo of the structure that I talked about:

[image]

Comment: What is your specific problem? If they were physical computers instead of VMs, do you know how you'd arrange this? What do you think is different because they're VMs?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't done it with physical computers either, that's why I am a bit confused how to do it. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the default gateway of VM2 to VM1, so that data between VM2 and Server will pass VM1.
2. Add a route on Host saying that data for VM2 will be passed to VM1.

If possible, try to give VM1 two virtual network interfaces, and build a private network just for VM1 and VM2.

Comment: if I make private network between VM1 and VM2 then host will be unaware of VM2 existance, isn't it? then it won't be able to ping VM2

Comment: It depends. In VMWare a virtual network is always bind to a virtual network adapter of the host, so the host will be able to communicate with VM2.